# Celery subtask get final result

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

When I try to use the example in `Celery` documentation which is `add` method with `subtask`, I can't get final result.

```
@task
def add(x, y, callback=None):
    result = x + y
    if callback:
        subtask(callback).delay(result)
    return result
```

When I call the task with;

```
>>> subadd = add.subtask(args=(5, ))
>>> r=add.apply_async(args=(1, 2,subadd))
>>> r.result
3
```

As it is seen, it returns `3` instead of `8`.

There is an ERROR on a worker when I run these part. I don't know why it is happenning.

```
[2013-06-27 07:49:18,080: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'devicemanagement.celery_task.add'.
```

What should I do to get 8 from result?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should it not be the following:

```
r = add.apply_async((1, 2), link=add.s(5))
r.result
```

[Celery - Linking (callbacks/errbacks)](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks)

Comment: I did something like r = add.apply_async((1, 2), link=other_task()) and other_task wouldnt get result from add

Comment: If you click the link included in my post you will see a little description about what `add.s` is with a link to further documentation on it. Basically, its a way of calling a subtask.

I can't really off much more help on this topic as it's been a couple of years since i've done any Pyhton/Django/Celery work.

Answer (score 1):

In >3.0 celery, chain is another cool choice:

```
from celery import chain

r = chain(add.s(1, 2), add.s(5))()
#or using '|' operator
r = (add.s(1, 2) | add.s(1))()
r.result
```